# Scatterplot of two column matrices

Tags: stata

I am currently having a problem with using Stata to draw a scatterplot when `A` (independent variable) and `B` (dependent variable) are two matrix vectors of size `1 x 1000`.

I used the command `twoway scatter`but this keeps failing because Stata deems `A` and `B` **not** to be variables. However, I defined `A` and `B` with the command `matrix define`.

The Variables window is empty and I am not sure why `A` and `B` are **not** variables.

Sample Code:

```
matrix define A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]' 

matrix define B = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]'

//drawing scatterplot with A vs B and overlay a horizontal line x = 5 onto the scatterplot.   
twoway scatter A B || xline(5)
```

Can I declare a matrix as a variable-type and save it so that I can re-use it with `twoway scatter`?

Comment: In Stata a variable is a column or field in the dataset (only). The terminology is standard statistically but not to many programmers, depending on what else they know. Many other entities in Stata have variable-like roles, such as macros, scalars, matrices and more besides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `svmat` command to first create the variables and then draw the graph:

```
clear
matrix define A = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)'
matrix define B = (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)'

svmat A
svmat B

twoway scatter A B, xline(5)
```

Matrices and variables in Stata are two different things.

Comment: As in the question, the matrices are of different sizes. In this case, that isn't fatal as `twoway` will use the first 9 observations in the dataset and ignore the 10th as it contains a missing value. For another way to copy matrices to variables. see https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0054